# PHP OOP - $pdo variable does not exist in function of the class

Tags: php, scope

I have problem with database connection.

Well, I include db.php file where PDO connection is initialized, then I check if $err variable is set and if it isn't, I create a new object and  try to use a method which builds a link id for me. But the problem is - method in this class does not see $pdo object at all.

index.php

```php
require_once 'db.php';
if (!isset($err)) {         
    $linkBuilder = new LinkBuilder();
    $link = $linkBuilder->buildLink();

    // ...
}
```

LinkBuilder.class.php

```php
<?php

class LinkBuilder {

    private $newLink;

    private function linkInUse($link) {
        try {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE link = :link');
            $stmt->bindValue(':link', $link);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $err = Constants::DB_ERR;
        }       
    }

    public function buildLink() : string {
        do {
            $this->newLink = rand(100, 999) . chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(65, 90));
        } while ($this->linkInUse($this->newLink));

        return $this->newLink;
    }


}
```

And also, is there anything to change to make this code better?

Thanks is andvance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in the PDO Object into your Class. In modern frameworks this will be done by dependency injection. In your case, you can start with adding a constructor to your link builder class.

```
class LinkBuilder {

    private $pdo;
    private $newLink;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    private function linkInUse($link) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE link = :link');
…
```

You have to change the initialization of your Object to

```
require_once 'db.php';
if (!isset($err)) {
    $linkBuilder = new LinkBuilder($pdo);
    $link = $linkBuilder->buildLink();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And what does this backslash means in constructor argument?

Comment: @mystickGuy Namespace reasons. You need to read more about OOP, namespace, ... . `\Foo\Bar\Baz` !== `\Baz`